# How to invoke A mx player in other application to play content from socket. in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-video-player

I am new to Android.
i am working on Application.
i done socket programming in c to transfer the video file to Android device under /sdcard
i can play the file from mx player.
i want to play the file while it is getting transmitted through socket.
so i want in my application once i start to receive the data, THE mx player should get intent to start , and start to play the data that is received till now.

comment if you need more clarification.

I just want to know how can i start MX player in my application and it will start to pick the data, that i am receiving through socket

PS: there is no HTTP streaming.

Comment: Will this not possible in Android???????